# In case of converation error , how to return to the application without checking other methods in pam

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

Let us say for my application APP ,  I have added a file in /etc/pam.d/APP and in APP I have defined the following:

```
    ....
    ....
    auth required method1
    auth required method2
    auth sufficient method3
    ....
    ....
```

In case of a conversation failure in method1 ,  how to return without calling pam_sm_authenticate in method2 and method3.

Thanks

-SomaSekhar

Answer (score 0):

If you make the first line:

```
auth requisite method1
```

then pam will return the failure immediately.